# Prove the equality of two line segments with circles

Tags: geometry

There are two circles. There are also two common "outside tangents" (they are marked red in the diagram) and one "inside tangent" which is marked blue. (I am not a native English speaker, I don't know how to call the outside and the inside tangents correctly) The inside tangent intersects the circles in points A and B and intersects two outside tangents in points A1 and B1. How can I prove that the line segment AA1 equals BB1?

[image: Direct&Inverse Tangents]

Comment: _The inside tangent intersects the circles in points A1 and B1_ Your diagram does not agree with this description ...

Comment: This has been fixed.

Comment: What else do you know about the two circles that you didn't mention? How do you know that $B_1B=5.67$ and $AA_1=5.67$?

Comment: Nothing else. The numbers are just to show that the problem is correct. (measured in GeoGebra). I guess we must find some congruent triangles here. @MercyKing

Comment: It is equivalent to show that $AB_1=BA_1$.

Comment: Yes, I have already figured up that. But none of the triangles seem to be congruent. What to do now?

Comment: I don't think this is true in general. Did you try other examples in Geogebra where this equality was also present?

Comment: Yes, and the equality remained the same. But when I switched to 15 numbers after the comma, the last number did not coincide.

Comment: Found the solution!

Comment: transverse tangent touches circles as tangent at $A,B$

Comment: reduced the field somewhat, hope OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E$ be the point of tangency of the lower tangent and the circle on the left. Then $AA_1 = AE$.

Let $F$ be the point of tangency of the lower tangent and the circle on the right.

$AA_1 = EF - A_1B$. $\ BB_1 = E_1F_1 (upper circle) - AB_1$.

Now $AA_1 = A_1B_1 - AB_1$; $BB_1 = A_1B_1 - A_1B$.

From these equations we get that $AB_1 = A_1B$.

Comment: [+1] I have tried to improve a little your presentation. In particular, use underscores between a letter and its index, example A underscore 1 makes $A_1$. Besides, something is missing in your argumentation: you should mention the **symmetry** of the figure with respect to axis $A_2C$.

Comment: @student28 How is $AA_1 = EF - A_1B$?.